# multi language conversion using calibre for Ebook

Tags: android, fonts, epub, calibre

I have Ebook in which there are 2 languages [Hindi  & English].
Now what is happening once is convert .pdf file to .epub it shows junk value for once language.

If i am passing Hindi font then it is displayed properly , but english is dipalye ad something else.

Can any one please help me how to get two fonts during file conversion in calibre.

Comment: Maybe you should not use Calibre for this project. There are other ways to manipulate an EPUB.. such as mounting it in Linux, or un-zipping in Windows.

Comment: Hi paul thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate how to do it ?

Comment: Not knowing your system.. hard to say. Check this http://support.redjumper.net/entries/25230713-How-to-manually-edit-an-ePub-file. Once you open it, you can read the source files. You could probably cut and paste the text into the end format you want.

Comment: i tried with thisactually i am having 2 fonts 1 gujarati and 1 english     http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/edit.html          https://code.google.com/p/sigil/              http://blogs.datalogics.com/2013/10/09/embedding-a-font-into-an-epub-file/   should this will work ?

Comment: @user2903354 what is the final solution (assuming you've found it)?